# MeteorJS: 'Server sent add for existing id' on reconnection

Tags: meteor

When the client loses connection an tries to reconnect with the server, I'm receiving this error (with the id of one of my objects). This only happens on the deployed app on `heroku`. I couldn't reproduce it on `localhost`.

I can reproduce it manually (only on prod) by quickly calling a succession of `Meteor.disconnect()` and `Meteor.reconnect()`. If I wait a couple of seconds between this 2 calls, the error doesn't occur, so I think it's some race condition.

I think it's something I've messed with, as I cannot reproduce this on a sample meteorpad app (same release of Meteor).

I'm using Meteor 1.0.

Any leads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku doesn't support sticky sessions. See "random page reloading issue" on http://joshowens.me/modulus-vs-heroku-vs-digital-ocean/.

Comment: Thanks for pointing on the right direction. So when I lose the connection Heroku destroys the session?

Comment: Yeah, according the article. I haven't tested myself though.